# How Do I Set the Line Width for a Single Stroke in Prawn

Tags: prawn

I'm trying to set the width of a stroke line in prawn for a single line. What I'd like to do is something like ...

`pdf.stroke_horizontal_line(0, bounds.width, :at => row*spacing, :line_width => 10)`

This doesn't work, and so I'm having to get the current line width, save it, set the new line width, draw the line, and then put the original line width back. Not the end of the world, but it seems like this should be built in and I have a feeling I may be missing something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I got from Gregory Brown via the Prawn Google Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prawn-ruby/w80AYnHo2X8) ...

`pdf.mask(:line_width) do 
  pdf.line_width (row % DARK_LINE_SPACING == 0) ? DARK_LINE_WIDTH : pdf.line_width 
  pdf.stroke_horizontal_line(0, bounds.width, :at => row*spacing) 
end`

Basically, you'll need to use the undocumented feature `mask` for this.